# Concentric Squares in Python with Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Trying to make concentric squares in python with Turtle. Here's my attempt:

```
import turtle
def draw_square(t, size):
   for i in range(4):
       t.forward(size)
       t.left(90)
wn = turtle.Screen()
dan = turtle.Turtle()

sizevar = 1
for i in range(10):
   draw_square(dan,sizevar)
   sizevar += 20
   dan.penup()
   dan.backward(sizevar/ 2)
   dan.right(90)
   dan.forward(sizevar / 2)
   dan.left(90)
   dan.pendown()
```

I'm not sure why they aren't concentric, my `dan.backward(sizevar/2)` and
`dan.forward(sizevar/2)` lines seem to move the square down and to the left too much?

Comment: Are you using python2 or python3?

Comment: @Lalaland, using python3.

Comment: Do you really want the first square to be 1 pixel?

Comment: Yes, unless that causes added complication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
import turtle
def draw_square(t, size):
   for i in range(4):
       t.forward(size)
       t.left(90)
wn = turtle.Screen()
dan = turtle.Turtle()
sizevar = 1
for i in range(10):
   draw_square(dan, sizevar)
   sizevar += 20
   dan.penup()
   dan.backward(10)
   dan.right(90)
   dan.forward(10)
   dan.left(90)
   dan.pendown()
```

Each square is only 10 pixels outside the previous.

Comment: Wonderful! For some reason I didn't grasp that sizevar / 2 wouldn't be moving by the same distance each time.

Answer (score 1):

Concentric squares begs to be done with a recursive algorithm (as opposed to iterative):

```
import turtle

def draw_square(t, size):
    for i in range(4):
        t.forward(size)
        t.left(90)

def recursive_draw(t, x, y, size):
    if (size < 200):
        t.penup()
        t.goto(x, y)
        t.pendown()
        draw_square(t, size)
        x -= 10
        y = x
        size += 20
        recursive_draw(t, x, y, size)

wn = turtle.Screen()
dan = turtle.Turtle()
recursive_draw(dan, 0, 0, 1)
```

It seems easier to reason about the code this way:

Base case: size must not exceed 200
Approach strategy: increase size by 20